# Getting img.id is not a function error when calculating VCI

Tags: google-earth-engine, error

I try to calculate VCI, when I run this code I got an error

> img.id is not a function

How to fix this problem?

```
//Image listing
var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1").filterBounds(table).select('NDVI');

var modis_list = [];
for(var i = 6; i <=10; i++) {
  for(var j = 2000; j <=2019; j++){
    modis_list.push(modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
                          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(j, j, 'year')));
  }
}
print(modis_list);

//VCI calculation
var vci = modis_list.map(function(img){
 var id = img.id();
 var min =  img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(), geometry,250).get('NDVI');
 var max = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(), geometry,250).get('NDVI');
 return img.expression(
   "(NDVI-min)/(max-min)",{
     "NDVI" : img,
     "max" : ee.Number(max),
     "min" : ee.Number(min)
   }).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});
print(vci)
```

I have no prior knowledge about the Google earth engine, I just try to learn.

Answer (score 2):

`modis` is an `ImageCollection`. `modis.filter(...)` returns a smaller `ImageCollection`. Therefore, the elements of `modis_list` are not images, but image collections.

There are two possibilities here, depending on what you want to happen *if your filter matches more than one image.*

- If you want *all* the images, then what you need to do is take your separate collections and *flatten* them into one collection. You can do that like so:

  ```
  var modis_filtered_flattened = 
      ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(modis_list).flatten());
  var vci = modis_filtered_flattened.map(function(img){
      ....
  ```
- If you want *any one* of the images, but only one per date, then you can use `.first()` to get the first image of the collection. (This will usually be the oldest matching image.)

  ```
  modis_list.push(modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
                       .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(j, j, 'year'))
                       .first());    // added this call
  ```

  However, if you do this, there's an efficiency problem in your script too: `modis_list` is a client side list, and when you map over it and print it, you end up sending *one compute request to Earth Engine per list element*. This is unnecessarily slow. To fix it, just convert the list to an ImageCollection: write `ee.ImageCollection(modis_list).map(...)` instead of `modis_list.map(...)`. This will result in a single server-side map operation.